# How to calculate Big O of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I want to calculate Big O of `x++` in below algorithm.

```
for (int i = 2;i < n;i*=2)
    for(int j = i;j < m;j*=j)
       x++;
```

I think a lot about it, but I can't solve it. How can I solve it?

Comment: Big-O notation in terms of **which variable**?  `m` or `n`?

Comment: In both of them.It depends on both of them.

Comment: The asymptotic behaviour is really only affected by `m`.  As soon as `n` exceeds `m` then the runtime won't increase.

Comment: "I think a lot about it" - what have you thought so far?

Comment: This case is very interesting. Thank you for having shared it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
O(lg(n) * lg(lg(m)))
```

at most `lg(n)` for outer loop and `lg(lg(m))` for the other.

EDIT: more help to prove:

lets change the variables :

```
nn = lg(n);
mm = lg(m);
```

the code will become:

```
for (int i = 1;i < nn;i++)
    for(int j = i;j < mm;j *= 2)
        x++;
```

now the runtime will be `O(nn * lg(mm))`.

EDIT(2): the bound can become tighter(because we have `j = i` in the second loop, not `j = 1`)

if `nn >= mm` then `(x++) = theta(mm * lg(mm)) = theta(lg(m) * lg(lg(m)))`

and

if `nn < mm`  then `(x++) = theta(nn * lg(mm)) = theta(lg(n) * lg(lg(m)))`

Comment: Are you sure we can't get a tighter bound by knowing that it uses `j=i` instead of `j=1`?

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, the outer loop is O(log<sub>2</sub>(*n*)) as *i* is doubled with each iteration from 2 until *n* exclusive. So:

> 2<sup>*x*</sup> < *n*
>   ⇔ log<sub>2</sub>(2<sup>*x*</sup>) < log<sub>2</sub>(*n*)
>   ⇔ *x* < log<sub>2</sub>(*n*)

So it requires at most log<sub>2</sub>(*n*) iterations of the outer loop until `i < n` is no longer fulfilled, thus O(log(*n*)).

The inner is a little tricky as the current value of *i* of the outer loop is used to initialize *j* of the inner loop. Additionally, *j* is multiplied with itself (i. e. *j*<sup>2</sup>) with every iteration. So:

> *j*<sup>2<sup>*x*</sup></sup> < *m*
>   ⇔ log<sub>*j*</sub>(*j*<sup>2<sup>*x*</sup></sup>) < log<sub>*j*</sub>(*m*)
>   ⇔ 2<sup>*x*</sup> < log<sub>*j*</sub>(*m*)
>   ⇔ log<sub>2</sub>(2<sup>*x*</sup>) < log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>*j*</sub>(*m*))
>   ⇔ *x* < log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>*j*</sub>(*m*))

So it requires at most log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>*j*</sub>(*m*)) iterations of the inner loop until the condition `j < m` is no longer fulfilled, thus O(log(log(*m*))). And if we ignore the bases, we can estimate the total complexity at O(log(*n*)·log(log(*m*))).

Answer (score 1):

`O(log(n) * log log(m))` the inner gets executed log log m times.

Comment: This implies that it's `O(log(n))` if `m` is fixed.  But this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to deduce the order of growth complexity of your algorithm, in methodical way. Unfortunately, I couldn't do so with `j` that variates at each innerloop iteration.

Nonetheless, I came up with a formula with a constant factor `k` instead of `j`.

Your algorithm, according to my suggestion, should look like the following:

```
for (int i = 2;i < n;i*=2)
    for(int j = i;j < m;j*=k)
       x++;
```

The solution is as follows:

[image]

[image]

Meanwhile, I will attempt to find a solution fitting exactly your initial problem.